# Redirecting bash script to /dev/null not executing?

Tags: bash, exec

so I'm very new to bash and I was making an installer for `build-essential` and `OpenSSL`. The problem is that It always stops after the first `exec` line. Here's my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Installing build-essential"
exec sudo apt-get install build-essential > /dev/null 2>&1
echo "Finished installing build-essential"
echo ""

echo "Installing OpenSSL"
exec sudo apt-get install openssl > /dev/null 2>&1
echo "Finished installing OpenSSL"
echo ""

echo "Updates complete!"
```

And here's the output:

```
Installing build-essential
[sudo] password for matthew:
```

Please keep in mind that I just started a few hours ago. Sorry for the dump question.

Comment: Why did you put exec in there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`exec` never returns to the calling script. It replaces the current process with the command following `exec`. Just remove the `exec` altogether, and let apt-get run like any other command.

Note: there are uses of `exec` that *do* return to the calling script, such as those that *only* do I/O redirection.

Comment: exec won't return when used to substitute the current process, but it won't halt the current script when used solely to manage file descriptors. Removing exec is the right thing to do, but the explanation is misleading.

Comment: Good clarification, I'll add that to my answer